# Woocommerce: How to add an alert or cap on product add-ons?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Using the product add-on plugin for Woocommerce to sell configurable products, I'm stumped on how to limit the number of add-ons per a product. For the current set-up, there will be no min or max per a add-on, but there is a max on the total add-ons that can be selected.  I'm using variable product set up, and each variation will have its own cap.  Any ideas on how to apply the cap or add an alert message when the cap is reached?

I'm using the following to generate the total of add-ons selected:

```
$cart.find('.addon').each(function() {

            var addon_options = 0;

            if ( $(this).is('.addon-input_multiplier') ) {
                if( isNaN( $(this).val() ) || $(this).val() == "" ) { // Number inputs return blank when invalid
                    $(this).val('');
                    $(this).closest('p').find('.addon-alert').show();
                } else {
                    if( $(this).val() != "" ){
                        $(this).val( Math.ceil( $(this).val() ) );
                    }
                    $(this).closest('p').find('.addon-alert').hide();
                }
                addon_options = $(this).val();
            }
            if ( ! addon_options )
                addon_options = 0;

            options_total = parseFloat( options_total ) + parseFloat( addon_options );
        } );
```

Please see an example at: http://21expressions.com/options_total.png

In this example, 8 add-ons were selected, which is the cap. How do I alert the user that the cap has been reached?

Answer (score 0):

I added divs with alert messages to an add-on template file. Each div has a css class corresponding to each of the product variation and its own alert message that will display when the cap is exceeded.  e.g. .large if size large is selected. These classes are set to display:none.  When a variation is selected, another class is added using the following:

```
$("#product-size").change(function(){
        $( "select option:selected").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")=="large")  {
                $(".large").addClass('l-cap');
                $(".small").removeClass('s-cap');
                } 

            else if ($(this).attr("value")=="small"){
                $(".small").addClass('s-cap');
                $(".large").removeClass('l-cap');
            }              

        });
}).change();
```

Using options_total from above (the initial post) and the new class added, an alert message is displayed using:

```
if ( options_total > 8) {
            $(".s-cap").show();
        }

        if ( options_total < 9) {
            $(".s-cap").hide();
        }

        if ( options_total > 10) {
            $(".l-cap").show();
        }

        if ( options_total < 11) {
            $(".l-cap").hide();
        }
```

Large has a cap of 10, and small has a cap of 8.  The above allows the alert message to display when the cap is exceeded, and to be hidden, when the user reduces the selected add-ons after exceeding the cap.